# Вывод изображения из БД

Tags: php, mysql, blob

Есть запрос к БД:

```
$result = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM $userstable WHERE `id`=$counter", $db);   

$years_life = mysql_result($result,0,1);
$full_name = mysql_result($result,0,2);
$temp_content = mysql_result($result,0,3);
$image = mysql_result($result,0,4); // а вот тут сидит картинка из blob'а
```

Потом html+php: `<img align='left' class='img' src='".$image."' height='300' width='400'>`

Но выводит данные файла, а не само изображение (браузер не понимает этот массив данных, так как браузеру ещё нужно и расширение файла знать для идентификации данных, blob-поле хранит лишь данные, а не расширения файлов, а браузер по заголовку данных файла не умеет определять его тип. И для чего тогда в заголовке хранятся данные типа файла, если без расширения они всё равно не пригодны? Ни ОС, ни браузеры по заголовкам самих данных файла не работают. Им нужно передавать заголовок Header - аля, расширение).

Вернёмся к теме вывода изображения.
Почитал на форумах, что вывода изображения из БД (MySQL), которое хранится в blob-поле, прямым запросом не существует. И надо писать отдельный php-обработчик с передачей заголовка (аля расширения).
Зачем тогда такое поле вообще существует в БД-MySQL? Это же сбивает с мыслей. И с более рационального и удобного пути программирования (положить файл в FS на сервер, а в БД лишь хранить его адрес).
И действительно ли в моём примере без стороннего php-обработчика изображений не обойтись?

Comment: вот как для вас [придумали](https://css-tricks.com/data-uris/).

Comment: Веб-программирование вообще сбивает с мыслей.

Comment: "положить файл в FS на сервер, а в БД ..." - к примеру, когда человек делает бэкап базы, он не хочет думать (сбиваться с мыслей) о дополнительных внешних файлах.

Comment: @I_CaR +1 - Спасибо Вам за фразу "сбивает с мыслей". Буду ее использовать "и в хвост, и в гриву".

Comment: @Igor 1 час назад - Бывает, что человек бэкапит одну лишь БД без фалов проекта? Согласен, но лишь на мелкопериодичные бэкапы (мимолётные такие бэкапчики), а если нормальный бэкап делать? Разве без фалов его делают?

Comment: @Igor  - сбивает с мыслей, потому что я решил сделать именно через blob. Через FS слишком просто. Умный в гору не пойдёт, умный откроет горный институт, выпустит специалистов, приобретёт технику и прорубит в горе тоннель.

Comment: @zRrr - Спасибо! Подходил к этому, но не знал про `base64_encode`

Comment: @I_CaR - У нас, видимо, разночтения в терминологии. Что такое "файлы проекта"? Если это файлы php приложения, то к данным (и их архиву/бэкапу) такие файлы не относятся, хранятся в системе контроля версий, которая, в свою очередь, тоже периодически бэкапится. Приложений, работающих с одной и той же базой, может быть несколько. Если "файлы проекта" - что-то другое, то я Вас не до конца понял, прошу прощения.

Comment: @Igor - Я вас теперь тоже понял. Я работаю с малым и средним бизнесом (чаще с малым), там системы контроля версии не применяются. Поэтому бэкапится всё ручками.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Параметр src у тега img подразумевает, что там будет именно url картинки. этот url может быть вида `http://yousite.ru/image.php?id=$id` и тогда ваша image.php достанет из блоба саму картинку и передаст ее браузеру в двоичном виде (как есть), не забыв при этом выставить правильный Content-type `header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');`

Либо, второй вариант, вы можете все таки отдать картинку сразу, при этом в IMG SRC надо положить ссылку специального вида, начинающуюся на `data:`, причем картинка должна быть закодирована в base64 кодировке. Подробнее в [Википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data:_URL). Но для этого способа есть существенные ограничения, например в большинстве случаев такой URL не должен превышать 4КБ. А это base64, при таком кодировании объем информации увеличивается на 1/3, таким образом максимально может влезть картинка порядка 3 КБайт.

А что касается MySQL - это вообще СУБД она разрабатывалась для многих целей и далеко не для того, что бы ее использовали в PHP при выводе на страницы web-сайтов. Поэтому говорить о ее возможностях в ключе "зачем же это, раз это не нужно в web" некорректно. Никто не мешает написать программу на C++, которая будет скажем сканировать изображения книг, распознавать их, класть в БД MySQL содержимое и на всякий случай сохранять в blob изначальное изображение. И использоваться такая БД будет скажем в каком нибудь приложении - читалке книг написаном на Java и работающем собственно на читалке таких книг, без всякого браузера.

А по поводу заголовков файлов скажу - вы не правы, браузеры по заголовку файла отлично понимают что это такое, вы можете дать файлу расширение .jpeg, а внутри будет картинка в формате png и браузер ее отлично отобразит. Заголовки внутри самого файла для этого и нужны, что бы можно было всегда корректно определить содержимое не смотря на кривое расширение. И кстати, если вы будете отдавать картинку как я написал в варианте 1 то для браузера это будет файл с расширением .php, но это не помешает ему отобразить эту картинку. И ОС, за исключением windows, работают именно по содержимому файлов. Да и в windows расширение используется только как затравка. Не обязана ОС знать изначально все форматы файлов на свете. Сделаете вы завтра свой формата изображений, вы думаете все ОС сразу о нем узнают и начнут понимать по содержимому что это картинка ?

Comment: Я имел ввиду не сам тип файла, а именно его привязку к типам. Png - это из "Content-Type: image/*"
А если я отберу расширения у mp3,  txt и jpg, то ни OS, ни браузеры не будут понимать, что это за файлы. Почему они не могут привязываться к ПО (или обрабатываться браузерами) исходя из их структуры данных? Вот я про что. Про заголовок файла, который внутри самого файла. По ним ещё расширение можно восстанавливать ( в случае его утраты, не часто но и такое бывает)

Comment: Я думаю это из за перестраховки. Что бы выполнялось именно то, что задумано. Я могу сделать скажем JS скрипт, который будет начинаться `BM=new Date;` или `PE=new Date`, и это совершенно не значит, что первый скрипт надо толковать как BMP картинку, а второй, как исполнимый файл Windows, А ведь эти первые 2 буквы - основной признак этих форматов на который все ориентируются ... Формат внутри файла уже для программы _готовой_ понимать этот формат, т.е. обработчика изображений или загрузчика исполнимых файлов

Comment: Спасибо за, действительно, познавательные ответы от вас.
И тогда последний вопрос, который родился из вашего ответа - какой вариант, с точки зрения оптимизации, оптимальнее или же рациональнее в использовании (буду его и придерживаться в разработке):
`http://yousite.ru/image.php?id=$id` или `base64_encode`?

Comment: Это пожалуй от ситуации зависит. Ограничения на картинки base64 вы видели, большую не положишь. В принципе, если картинка будет встроена в html то она откроется быстрее, потому как отдельный запрос не нужен. Но тут уже вопрос к природе картинок. они же в таком виде кешироваться не будут и будут идти с сервера при каждом запросе. Если отдавать вторым способом, то можно поставить заголовки для обязательного кеширования браузером (особенно если уверены, что сама картинка под данным ID не изменится со временем), что так же ускорит и клиента и уменьшит нагрузку на сервер